# Supporting style files of tex file

Tags: packages, journal

The journal asked me to provide them "supporting files so they will be able to uploading the same. They asked me to send them the `tex` file and the style files of the tex file".
I sent them all the files that are in the relevant directory: `.tex`, `.pdf`, (all figures), `.bib`, `.sty`, `.clo`, `.cls` and `.synctex.gz`.

[image]

What else can I send them?
I produced a `pdf` from `TeXstudio 2.11.2` latex file 
Here is the packages I use:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
    %!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
    %%BoundingBox: 19 19 221 221
    %%CreationDate: Mon Sep 29 1997
    %%Creator: programmed by hand (JK)
    %%EndComments
    gsave
    newpath
    20 20 moveto
    20 220 lineto
    220 220 lineto
    220 20 lineto
    closepath
    2 setlinewidth
    gsave
    .4 setgray fill
    grestore
    stroke
    grestore
\end{filecontents*}
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%
% \usepackage{mathptmx}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
%
% insert here the call for the packages your document requires
%\usepackage{latexsym}
% etc.
%

% \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{convert #1 \OutputFile}
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.tif}


\newcommand{\tvar}[2]{%
    \mathrm{#1}_{\mathrm{#2}}%
}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, makecell} %

%\\usepackage[symbol*]{footmisc}
%\usepackage[round]{natbib} 
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib} 
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}

%\usepackage{siunitx,etoolbox}
%\renewrobustcmd{\bfseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
%\renewrobustcmd{\boldmath}{}
%\newrobustcmd{\B}{\bfseries}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
% \journalname{myjournal}
%

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
```

Comment: Did they come back to you and ask for something specific? Your list seems to be complete…

Comment: Thanks @TeXnician very much. That's what I thought. I resent them the files again with .sty extension. Hope it will be OK.

Comment: You could use [bundledoc](https://ctan.org/pkg/bundledoc) to make a snapshot of all the dependencies and external resources used by your document.

Comment: Thanks @DG', is it the *.tar.gz file that is produced automatically by TeXstudio?

Comment: @Avi I don't use TeXstudio and don't know which files are produced by it, so I can't really tell....